# What templating languages are available cross-platform -- both on .Net and Java EE/LAMP?

Tags: templates, template-engine

XSLT, obviously.

[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) has a .Net port -- [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/) -- but it's pretty old. The last release was in 2003.

Anything else?  Is there a cross-platform version of [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)?

Ideally, I'm looking for something that will run on all three platforms -- .Net, Java EE, and LAMP.